# fprintf not working C

Tags: c, char, printf

I'm trying to make a simple program that writes to a .txt file, but this code won't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "main.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE *f = fopen("text.txt", "w+");
    char c[256];
    printf("What's your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", c);
    fflush(f);
    if (c!=NULL) 
    {
        printf("not null\n");
        int q = fprintf(f, "%s", c);
        printf("%d", q);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("null\n");
    }
    printf("Hello, %s\n", c);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

The `printf` returns that it's not null, and the `int q` returns whatever the length of the char is. Why isn't this writing to the file?

Comment: I tried your program on Microsoft Visual C++ and it works fine. I observe a text.txt file in the working directory. Can you share more details about your environment? Also, why are you including `main.h`?

Comment: `c` will never be null, no need to check that. Instead make sure `f` is not null.

Comment: And turn on some compiler warnings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't running with the correct permissions. Stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

> the printf returns that it's not null,

Thats because c is not null , since you have scanned your name string into it.

> Why isn't this writing to the file?

The program is working fine , on my system.

-- Edit --

```
FILE *f = fopen("text.txt", "w+");
if (NULL == f)
  perror("error opening file\n");
```

By doing the error handling this way , the exact reason (in your case permissions) , would be displayed,

Answer (score 0):

First off, you've declared `c` in local scope, so it will never be `NULL`. If you want to check whether or not the user entered anything, check the length of `c` after you've scanned in the string:

```
if (strlen(c) == 0) {
    ///
}
```

Second, check whether or not you have permission to write to the current working directory. You should be checking the return value of `fopen`:

```
if (!f) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open text.txt for writing\n");
}
```